# symfony - setting a different php class name for a table

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

My tables are named in a plural form - Models / Entities, is there a way to make the generated classes named Model / Entity?

(Don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using Propel as the ORM)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
propel:
  users:
    _attributes:    { phpName: User}
    name:           varchar(255)
```